# angularJS can I use params in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

there is a problem, I want to get something in directive
and I want to set it in html
so, how can set in html, and get in directive?

**there is html**

```
<div my-directive="Bob">
<div>
```

**directive.js**

```
App.directive('myDirective', function () {
  link: function () {
    console.log('xxx')
  }
})
```

how can I get `Bob` in directive?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using [`attrs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-)

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  console.log(attrs.myDirective); // Outputs Bob
}
```

The `attrs` object contains key-value pairs where the keys are the normalised attribute names of attributes on the element, and the values are the string values of each attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can  use **params** in directive.

> This is  **one-way** data binding solution

**controller**:

```
$scope.options = {one: "first, two: "second"};
```

**view**:

```
<div databinding="options"></div>
```

And in the **javascript**:

```
app.directive('databinding', function () {
   return{
      scope: {

        options: "@" //Can also use = here

      },
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

        console.log(scope.options);

      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I also want to known, what does `@` or `=` mean here?

Comment: @ Attribute string binding
= Two-way model binding
& Callback method binding